# Сan’t send Post-request to last.fm

Tags: javascript, last.fm

I'm trying to send a request like in the documentation, but it returns me a response: Invalid parameters - Your request is missing a required parameter

```
async function unlove_track(track_name,artist) {
            let body = {
                track: track_name,
                artist: artist,
                api_key: 'api_key',
                api_sig: 'api_sig',
                sk: 'sk',
                method: 'track.unlove'
            }
            let response = await fetch(`http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
                headers: {'User-Agent': '--------'}
            });
            response.json().then(res => {console.log(res)})
        }
```

[Screenshot from documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxmrw.png)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't make explicit mention of it, but if you look at [the API clients](https://www.last.fm/api/downloads) they link to (e.g. [this PHP one](https://github.com/matt-oakes/PHP-Last.fm-API/blob/master/src/lastfmapi/Api/BaseApi.php#L241)) you can see that the request body is expected to be formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not the JSON you are using.

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to generate your data in that format.

Don't forget to include the `Content-Type` request header.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but now it gives a new error "Invalid method signature supplied", although I checked it 100 times, the signature must be correct, using it the request to obtain the session key works, but then it gives an error

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Stuck on the same thing

Comment: @Foxyboy if Quentin has solved this particular issue, mark his answer as accepted and post your next problem as a new question. Surely, I can guide with the signature problem if not solved yet.